# How to change the owner for dashboard and reports?

Tags: reporting, dashboard, for, owner, change

Some dashboards and reports not working after disabling the left employee login.
So I want to assign a new owner to the existing dashboard and reports.
Could you guide me how to change the owner name for dashboard and reports?

Comment: Login as to-be owner and clone them (Save As..)

Answer (score 0):

If I look at [this idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdZuIUAV/changing-owner-of-reports-and-dashboards) at the Idea Exchange, then no, sorry, it is not possible to change the owner of dashboards or reports.